# If in Html calling a model

Tags: python, html, django

I have this model:

```py
class Canva(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=255)
    site = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=255)
    month = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=255)
    year = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

in html page: when I write {{ canva.month }}, it shows me the value JUNE

but when I write:

**{% if JUIN == canva.month %}**

**hello**

**{% else %}**

**goodbye**

**{% endif %}**

it always show me goodbye.

Comment: Well, you're spelling `JUNE` one place and `JUIN` another...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should compare it with a string, not with identifier, so:

```
{% if canva.month == 'JUNE' %}
  hello
{% else %}
  goodbye
{% endif %}
```

I would however *strongly* advise to use a `DateTimeField`, and not store dates as a collection of strings. It is easy to save for example `'JUIN'` instead of `'JUNE'`, and it makes comparing two dates (close to) impossible.